# Read a number of records from DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to make a DynamoDB query with DynamoDBMapper and retrieve only a number of matching records.

I have checked Mapper documentation and query expressions that it uses , but could not find any limiting parameter.

How can i achieve this with DynamoDBMapper?

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen the [withLimit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBQueryExpression.html#withLimit(java.lang.Integer)) attribute?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBQueryExpression.html